# React. Работа с таймером

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему не работает код:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Timer = ({ timeoutSec }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(timeoutSec);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);

  return <div>timer: ${counter}</div>;
};

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{Timer(60)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: <h2>{Timer({timeoutSec: 60})}</h2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что Вы используете синтаксис деструктурирующего присваивания, которое позволяет извлекать данные из массивов или объектов при помощи синтаксиса, подобного объявлению массива или литералов в объекте. Вот ваш код:

```
const Timer = ({ timeoutSec }) => { ... }
```

В приведенном коде из параметра переданного объекта в метод `Timer` извлекается поле `timeoutSec`. Это означает, что в переданном объекте в `Timer` - должно быть поле `timeoutSec`, иначе вы получите `undefined`. Решение проблемы простое, передать объект с таким параметром, либо изменить параметр метода.

1. Вызвать таймер вот так: `Timer({ timeoutSec: 60 })`
2. Вызвать таймер так: `Timer(60)`, при этом изменить метод: `const Timer = (timeoutSec) => { ... }`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: А вы неплохо React знаете?

Comment: А как React взаимодействует с backend'ом? Он может в связке с PHP, Python работать?